# After post saved to database, how do I route to another ejs page

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, redirect, ejs

How can I load another page after a post in node.js with ejs.

```
//router
function router() {
   ticketRouter.route("/create/submit") // tied to submit from one ejs
      .post(dataControllerThatTakesCareOfThis) // works fine

    // either in here, or even the controller I suppose I want to load another page after the submit takes place?
     res.redirect(200, '/load:postSubmit') // doesn't work
     res.send({ redirect: '/load:postSubmit' }) // great for ajax response only

}

module.exports = router;
```

So is the above something that you can do in node.js without having to go back out to the client with some information and then have it ask the question in order to process it? Is there a 'redirect' or a way to route the response like this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm very confused by what you've written here.  You're calling on 'res.redirect' and 'res.send' but you aren't inside an express middleware or http callback.  Are you really showing the complete and correct code?

Comment: no it isn't the complete code, rather an example of what I am attempting. in general I was just asking whether or not the handler of a post (routing, controller) could forward to another routing handler instead of sending response like ajax all the way back to the client, so that is can turn around and ask for another page. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you're using ExpressJS and EJS is your Template Engine :

You should handle your redirection into the *dataControllerThatTakesCareOfThis* function.

These two lines :

> ```
> // either in here, or even the controller I suppose I want to load another page after the submit takes place?
>  res.redirect(200, '/load:postSubmit') // doesn't work
>  res.send({ redirect: '/load:postSubmit' }) // great for ajax response only
> ```

Won't work because they are using the **res** object which is not defined here but in the callback of the Post method of the Router object.

More info in the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/fr/4x/api.html#app.post.method)

Comment: interesting. so that function is a controller function for the router to leverage, and I have tried res.redirect(200, url) there to, but it seems to print out OK, posting to: /load:postSubmit as a text response

Comment: This is the answer, because the approach is wrong as I suspected. I need to chain the middleware callbacks and use next(). Thanks